# Css from child component will affect the entire page

Tags: css, angular, angular7

I have a page and the page is split in two. Part of the page is child1, part is child 2.

Hierarchy

```
Parent
   Child1
   Child2
```

Below are the css included in the page

```
Child1 ->   z-index: 1
Child2 ->   z-index: 2
```

I want to give a backdrop to the entire page when a button in child1 is clicked. Css is as follows

```
.backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(16,19,22,.6);
    z-index: 5;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

But this only takes up the child1 component. I want it to cover the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EventEmitter

It is best to not fight against Angulars style encapsulation and just throw an event to the parent to let it handle the styling.

In your child component script:

```js
@Output() styleEvent = new EventEmitter();

onClick() {
  this.styleEvent.emit();
}
```

Child component template:

```html
<button (click)="onClick()">Add Style</button>
```

In the parent script:

```js
styleOn = false

handleStyleEvent() {
  this.styleOn = !this.styleOn
}

getStyle() {
  return this.styleOn ? 'backdrop' : ''
}
```

In the parent template:

```html
<div [ngClass]="getStyle()">
  <app-one (styleEvent)="handleStyleEvent()"></app-one>
  <app-two></app-two>
</div>
```

*You can add the styling to your parent stylesheet (or `styles.css` if you want it to be globally available).*

Here's an example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zun6dx).

Comment: The backdrop z-index in the Stackblitz example is negative so you can keep pressing the button, but of coarse it doesn't have to be if you render a popup or something.